# How can I read Kotlin documentation

Tags: kotlin, documentation, interpretation

I am beginer with Kotlin, I am readig the official [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)

My problem is that not sure how can I interpretate the documentation, by ex:

```
inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R
```

How should read this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have linked here is an **api reference** in the official documentation.I guess you are having troubles understanding the syntax of Generics here.

1. Try going through the [Generics section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) first.
2. If you still don't understand it maybe you should go through the [Getting Started](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) section once again and get comfortable with the basic syntax of functions, inline functions, lambdas, generics etc.